# Excel VBA - best practice to call a function upon detecting a change in cell value

Tags: excel, vba

I've experimented with many different ways to automatically call a macro/function upon detecting a change in a certain range of cells
Something along the lines of:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Range ("PartNumbers") = "B6:B18"
    If Not Application.Intersect(Range(Target.Address), Range("PartNumbers")) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        decodepartnumber (Target.Address)
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

I'm wondering if there's a better approach, namely to:
1. avoid losing undo history
2. trigger a function ONLY when a value changes.

The application is meant to monitor a `range (B6:B18)` and if I enter a product part number in B6, the function `decodepartnumber` will fill in the Product Description in C6, and product Price in D6.

I initially had coded this with B6 filled in with `=part_desc(A6)` and `=part_price(A6)` in C6, but it meant a user couldn't edit the resulting value easily..

Any ideas would be appreciated on best practices or alternative approaches would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an alternative approach: You could use a function to trigger a change (calculation must be set to xlAutomatic)

In a module:

```
Function ValChange(Cell2Follow As Range) As String
 Evaluate "decodepartnumber(" & ActiveCell.Row & ")"
End Function

Sub decodepartnumber(rw As Long)
Cells(rw, 3).Value = "description ":   Cells(rw, 4).Value = "price"
End Sub
```

In a cell (somewhere on your sheet): =ValChange(PartNumbers)

When a change is made in your range "PartNumbers" the Function will fire (your Point .2)
And you still have the Undo option with one caveat: Undoing works only for and untill the first Undo in your PartNumbers range.

(+ Multiple selection-change is not taken into account)

Comment: This seems to work!!! let me play with this approach for a bit.. Thanks! (Sorry i'm new... my upvotes don't count)

Answer (score 0):

I think you will always lose the undo history when using vba.
**Edit: never mind the below does keep the undo history, but will raise the change of cell again.

Take a look at this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
 Dim KeyCells As Range

 Set KeyCells = Range("B6:B18")

 If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
       Is Nothing Then
    ' Display a message when one of the designated cells has been
    ' changed.
    ' Place your code here.
    MsgBox "Cell " & Target.Address & " has changed."

 End If
End Sub
```

Comment: it will kill the undo history the moment any value is changed by the code... for instance                 


 
`MsgBox "Cell " & Target.Address & " has changed."
    Range(Target.Address).Offset(0, 1).Value = 12345
`